# MySQl, join/merge 2 tables without shared column and ordering by a common column

Tags: mysql, join

I have two tables with identical structures handling distinct data. I want to merge them, add a text field indicating where the data for that row came from, and order by a common field.

TABLE1

```
ID|NAME|YEAR  

1,'peter',2008
2,'edward',2010
```

---

TABLE2

```
ID|NAME|YEAR

1,'compadre',2009
2,'vika',2011
```

---

DRAFT of query ( obviously is erroneous )

```
select * from TABLE1 JOIN TABLE2 order by YEAR asc
```

expected result:

```
1,'peter','iamfromTABLE1',2008
1,'compadre','iamfromTABLE2',2009
2,'edward','iamfromTABLE1',2010
2,'vika','iamfromTABLE2',2011
```

I know I can do this using PHP/MySQL, but is there not a more elegant way like the "One Simple Query".

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use a Union query and literals:

```
SELECT ID, Name, 'iamfromTABLE1' as indicator, Year
FROM Table1
UNION
SELECT ID, Name, 'iamfromTABLE2' as indicator, Year
FROM Table2
ORDER BY Year
```

---

EDIT: `as indicator` added on recommendation of iim.hlk

Comment: you are, THE MAN ( regards from Monterrey, México ) :B

Comment: a little correction to your code is **'iamfromTABLE1' as indicator**, **'iamfromTABLE2' as indicator** to return the virtual column named 'indicator' instead of 'iamfromTABLE1' as column name.

Comment: Ah! Good to know! I didn't know literals needed to be identified as such in MySQL, but it makes sense.