# Join in one column to another table

Tags: php, mysql, sql, join

I know this question is very common on Stack, but I can't seem to find an answer or a snippet of code that actually solves my problem...

I have two tables, `accounts` and `orders`. I want to write a SQL statement to pull `Order ID`, `Date`, `Total` and `Status` from `orders`, and also `Username` from `accounts`.

The statement would be something like this:

```
$ohsql = "select * from orders where Username = '". $login_session ."'";
```

Obviously `Username` will come from the `accounts` table, but the principal is there. I am missing the `join` as I am clueless about it!

Comment: select ... from t1 JOIN t2 on t1.col = t2.col where ...

Comment: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/join.html

Comment: `$ohsql = "select * from orders,accounts where Username = '". $login_session ."' and accounts.OrderID = orders.OrderID";` - you may want to add more columns to the where clause if OrderID is not a suitable join (Date probably)

Comment: Is any thing common in both the table. Like UserID or OrderID like?

Comment: There is nothing in common. Would that mean the statement provided by Giles will not work?

Comment: Nothing in common? But how do you find a username?

Comment: The username is in the accounts table. However, I'll add "AccountID" to orders which is in accounts as it'll be easier to find orders. :)

Comment: see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19222335/joining-multiple-tables-without-common-key and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8001880/mysql-join-merge-2-tables-without-shared-column-and-ordering-by-a-common-column

Comment: I've tried reading posts like that and it confuses me. I'll try again.

Comment: thing is, is your column name `Order ID` like that, with the space? If so, did you take the space into account? It requires special attention when there is a space.

Comment: The table name is "OrderID". :)

Answer (score 2):

You need to 'link' the two tables. For that do something like :
- add a column `accountid` to Orders table; so this tells us, which order belongs to which user . We then use this info in our JOIN.

Easy way to do it in 2 queries :

```
// get the id value of the username
$id = select id from accounts table where username = $login_session 

// use that in the JOIN
select * from orders JOIN accounts ON orders.accountid = accounts.id where accounts.id = $id
```

Comment: is error reporting on ? What do var_dump of $row  and $id show ?

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that your orders table contains the accountId and your accounts table containing the user name use following query

```
$ohsql = "select o.*, a.username from orders o
INNER JOIN accounts a ON a.id = o.accountId
WHERE a.username = '". $login_session ."'";
```

Let me know if you face any issue